# IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant

Tags: java, база-данных, исключения, jdbc, enum

*Использую JDBC для чтения и записи объектов в DB.*

*В одном из объектов (Coupon) есть поле типа CouponType (что является enum CouponType).*

***enum CouponType:***

```
package db_package;

public enum CouponType {
    RESTURANS("RESTURANS"), 
    ELECTRICITY("ELECTRICITY"), 
    FOOD("FOOD"),
    HEALTH("HEALTH"),
    SPORTS("SPORTS"),
    CAMPING("CAMPING"),
    TREVELLING("TREVELLING");


    private String type;

    CouponType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String type() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

*Когда я выполняю метод getCoupon я создаю новый купон заполняю его поля данными из DB, и возвращаю.*

***class CouponDBDAO() - getCoupon, creatCoupon methods:***

```
public void createCoupon(Coupon coup) {
        Statement st;
        try {
            st = getStatment();
            if(st != null){
            st.execute(SQLConstantsQuery.INSERT_INTO_COUPON_VALUES
                    + "(" + coup.getId() + ",'" + coup.getTitle()
                    + "','" + coup.getStartDate() + "','" + coup.getEndDate() + "'," 
                    + coup.getAmount() + ",'" + coup.getType() + "','" + coup.getMessage()
                    + "'," + coup.getPrice() + ",'" + coup.getImage() + "');");
            System.out.println("Coupon " + coup.getTitle() + " added to DB");
            }else{
                throw new UpdateException("The Statement is null...");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | UpdateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public Coupon getCoupon(long id) {
        //Создание нового объекта Coupon для возврата
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
        ResultSet rs;
        String typeFromDB;
        try {
            //Метод getStatment() возвращает Statment далее выполняем SQL запрос и получаем объект Coupon.
            rs = getStatment().executeQuery(SQLConstantsQuery.SELECT_COUPON_BY_ID + id );
            while(rs.next()){
                coupon.setId(rs.getLong(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_ID));
                coupon.setTitle(rs.getString(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_TITLE));
                coupon.setStartDate(rs.getDate(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_START_DATE));
                coupon.setEndDate(rs.getDate(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_END_DATE));
                coupon.setAmount(rs.getInt(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_AMOUNT));
                typeFromDB = rs.getString(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_TYPE);
                CouponType ct = CouponType.valueOf(typeFromDB.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                coupon.setType(ct);
                coupon.setMessage(rs.getString(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_MESSAGE));
                coupon.setPrice(rs.getDouble(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_PRICE));
                coupon.setImage(rs.getString(SQLConstantsQuery.COUPON_IMAGE));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coupon;
    }
```

*Все бы хорошо но когда я делаю setType то метод ждет от меня значение типа CouponType, а у меня String.
Но не беда, я делаю:*

```
 CouponType ct = CouponType.valueOf(typeFromDB.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

*и передаю* `ct` *в метод setType.*

*Теперь можно запустить Main создав перед этим несколько объектов*

***Main class:***

```
public class MainTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            CouponDBDAO c = new CouponDBDAO();
            Coupon coupon = new Coupon(6, "title4", "message3", "image3", 5.2, "2015-11-23", "2015-12-23", 773,
                    CouponType.HEALTH);
            System.out.println(c.getCoupon(coupon.getId()));
        }
    }
```

***class Coupon:***

```
public class Coupon {
    private long id;
    private String title, message, image;
    private double price;
    private Date startDate, endDate;
    private int amount;

    private CouponType type;
    protected static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.US);

    public Coupon(){

    }

    public Coupon(long id, String title, String message, String image, double price, 
            String startDate, String endDate, int amount, CouponType type) throws ParseException {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.startDate = formatter.parse(startDate);
        this.endDate = formatter.parse(endDate);
        this.amount = amount;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return formatter.format(this.startDate);
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return formatter.format(this.endDate);
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public CouponType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(CouponType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coupon [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", message=" + message + ", image=" + image + ", price="
                + price + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", amount=" + amount + ", type=" + type
                + "]";
    }
}
```

*Ну и теперь самое главное что я хочу спросить, после запуска я получаю ошибку:*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant db_package.CouponType.ELECTRICITY                                       
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at db_package.CouponType.valueOf(CouponType.java:1)
    at db_package.CouponDBDAO.getCoupon(CouponDBDAO.java:108)
    at db_package.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:54)
```

*и немогу понять по чему? Ведь есть такая константа.
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.*

Comment: Проверьте, какая строка передается в valueOf, скорее всего там название которое не соответствует ни одному Enum'у

Comment: а как вы записываете объект  в БД?

Comment: вам надо сделать парсер в CouponType а не делать. toUpperCase

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov передается строка со значением HEALTH, а записываю в DB через метод createCoupon.

Comment: @tarasula смотри, если бы там был HEALTH то valueOf норм отработал. Тут нет чудес, значит ты кривую строку передаешь.

Comment: @Artem Konovalov смотри, в методе main я создаю объект Coupon и последний параметер который я передаю он CouponType.HEALTH. Далее записываю объект, а потом пытаюсь взять (прочитать) объект по его ID. Считываю параметер type из ResultSet как String и его значение равно HEALTH. Далее делаю valueOf...

Comment: выводи в лог typeFromDB и посмотри что приходит

Comment: @SeniorAutomator typeFromDB = HEALTH

Comment: @tarasula это ты из логов достали ли так считаешь\думаешь что так и будет?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator это System.out.print(typeFromDB); в консоле.

Answer (score 3):

***Нашел!***

***Проблема была в том что значение получаемое из базы данных было с большим колличеством пробелов. Не смотря на то что все это время я работал с Debuger-ом каким то чудесным образом этого не заметил.***

*Дописал строчку:*  `typeFromDB = typeFromDB.trim();` *и все заработало.*

*Все это дело не было видно в логах но в режиме* ***Debug*** *это хорошо видно в окне* ***Variable***.

Comment: Видимо, у вас соответствующее поле в БД имеет тип `char`, а должно быть `varchar`.